# How to tackle the problems of optimistic locking (Versioning) in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I know, that can use the following code to implement optimistic locking, however the disadvantages are that the user or application must refresh and retry failed updates. How to tackle the issue so users or application do not trapped in such failed errors?

```
public class User {

 @Id
 private Long id;

 @Version
 private Long version;


}
```

Comment: That is the entire point.  To force the user refresh to see if they still want to make the change based on seeing the latest information.  What is the behaviour you actually want from your application?

Comment: if the changes are not the same for example user 1 changed field 1 and user 2 changes field 2 it does not show any error to users

Comment: so you want optimistic locking that only applies to individual columns?

Answer (score 3):

You can [use](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch05.html) either optimistic locking using versions or pessimistic using DB locks.

**Optimistic** means that you **hope** that concurrent change will never come and if it will, one of these user will win and second (or third etc.) will have to update it's entity from DB and perform the change again. As it does not use any additional locking at DB layer, it just provides great throughput of your system/DB.

On the other hand you can use **pessimistic** locking which locks the entity once user starts to edit the entity. The lock is released at the same time as underlying transaction get commit/rollback. Nobody can fetch the entity from database so mostly the user needs to wait until commit of transaction of another user. Obvious advantage is *no such errors any more*, drawback is lower throughput.

Comment: This is common term I use to described situation when something uses locking :-) Once you edit one entity, one database row, it does not mean that there is only one row lock. In general it could mean that the whole table is locked because of the schema contains clustered index or index itself. Now suppose your website is used by 300 concurrent clients and you use pessimistic locking which cause table locks and all of the rest of 299 other client is blocked. It's better to use optimistic locking and solve possible collisions later.

Answer (score 3):

To address your question, you can "solve" the optimistic locking problem by applying several techniques. None of them are perfect, and depend on your scenario's, but this is what you can do:

### implement a retry-mechanism

You could retrieve the record from the database again, and try the update again. This can work if only new fields were changed. Otherwise, it could lead to confusement for your users. It could lead to inconsistencies as well, if a user took a decision based on the value of a field that has been changed by another user.

### tell the user to reload

You could tell the user to reload the page, tell hem that there have been changes, or reload the page for them. This forces them to do their work again potentially.

### take a different architectural approach

This requires some serious effort and possibly experience, but with a system that uses Event Sourcing (not necessarily CQRS), you just record events as they happen and then you can rebuild your entity from the events. This must match your domain though; not all domains are a good fit for ES.